# No puedo conectar mi base de datos en mi Hosting

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, pdo, hosting

Esta es mi conexión:

Usando *CodeIgniter*

```
$db['mysql'] = array(   
'dsn' => 'mysql:host=mysql.hostinger.co;dbname=u201535648_regis',
'hostname' => 'mysql.hostinger.co',
'username' => 'u201535648_germa',
'password' => 'password',
'database' => 'u201535648_regis',
'dbdriver' => 'pdo',

);
```

Esta es la conexion de mi local,no se muy bien como configurar el dsn

```
$db['mysql'] = array(
'dsn'   => 'mysql:hostname=localhost; dbname=1410inventory',
'hostname' => '',
'username' => 'root',
'password' => '',
'database' => '',
'dbdriver' => 'pdo',
```

);

Ésta es la conexión que tengo que hacer:

[image: ESTA ES LA CONEXION QUE TENGO QUE HACER]

Mi log tira ésto:

> ERROR - 2018-07-23 19:36:18 --> PDO: Invalid or non-existent subdriver

Por favor ayuda, es urgente.

Answer (score 0):

Según la [**documentación**](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html), si estás usando *PDO* lo más probable es que tengas que proveer también el *DSN (Data Source Name)*. Intenta hacerlo de esta manera:

```
// PDO
'dsn' => 'mysql:host=mysql.hostinger.co;dbname=u201535648_regis';
```

Answer (score 0):

yo he tenido muchos problemas parecido a los tuyo aveces era por otras cosas y casi siempre lo he solucionado en estas zonas.

Config

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://hostinger.co/';
```

Database

```
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => 'mysql.hostinger.co',
'username' => 'u201535648_germa',
'password' => 'password',
'database' => 'u201535648_regis',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => '',
```

htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```